# How to connect an Angular application to nodeJS or another backend, and executing an app.component.ts in the backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, backend

Basically my app.component.ts file dynamically produces a html which in turn provides forms for the user to fill in...

How do I connect this to a nodejs server, whilst maintaining all the functions of the TS file? so basically run our front end ng serve does, but do this using nodejs?

Comment: You can check Angular Universal to make your code server side https://angular.io/guide/universal.

Comment: Didn't quite lead me to the right place but reading about rendering the application due to research from your comment helped find a partial solution, so thank you very much!